# Lubuntu upgrade

Tags: lubuntu

I would like to upgrade from Lubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 but when I click upgrade it shows Ubuntu bionic beaver, will I end up with that or Lubuntu ? Is an old T41 thinkpad.

Comment: Since Lubuntu is a supported version of Ubuntu, the upgrade should leave you with Lubuntu 18.04.  I would strongly recommend that you backup your data, however, and disable third party repositories such as video drivers, before the upgrade.

Comment: Yes but will I end up with Lubuntu or Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 2):

Roughly speaking: Lubuntu is a Ubuntu without Gnome or Unity but with LXDE. When you upgrade, Ubuntu will upgrade some package, settings, etc. but it will not remove LXDE. Hence you will have Ubunut with LXDE, which is your Lubuntu.

**Short: Yes, you will end up with Lubuntu 18.04**

Please make a backup, because it allways can go something wrong. And if so, feel free to visit AskUbuntu again.

Comment: Thank-you, when you say backup do you mean system or just data ?

Comment: It depens on what do you need. If you want anyways a new System, you dont need to backup. If you have changed your system a lot, if you need some settings save - then backup the whole system.

Comment: Just don't want to start from scratch if upgrade goes sideways, always have data backed up to a usb drive.